# Woocommerce - Move titles over thumbnails of products in Category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, title, product

I need to move the titles of the products, while I am browsing the category page, over their thumbnails

**Details:**

I have created a shop page where I only display the categories.
Every category contains 1 to 10 products.

Once I click a category, I land on a page where I see all of the products in that category.

*I would like to see the titles of those products appearing over their thumbnails.*

Thank you

Comment: Please provide more details.  We'd love to help, but you don't give us enough information!  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (Please don't take this as something that scares you away from this community.  You can genuinely get great help here, you just have to provide more detail about your situation.)  Primarily, give us some code, show us what you have tried and why it didn't work, and give us any other information you think may be pertinent.

Comment: @Ecnalyr I've add some infos :) thank you

Comment: That's much better!  Almost there.  You should provide at least the code you're currently using.  That way people helping you have something to work with rather than having to go way out of there way to grab similar code.  You want to make it as easy as possible for someone to answer your question.  If all of the necessary information is here, someone is likely to answer the question rapidly.  If only some information is here, someone will be able to tell you that they need a specific piece of information to answer your question (that way you don't have to be perfect the first time you post).

Comment: The thought occurred that you may not be a programmer (this would be a great time to become one).  You may be someone just trying to put together a solution on a website you inherited.  If this is the case, you may need help not from stackoverflow, but from `woocommerce`'s support forum: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce .  We could definitely find the solution here, but stackoverflow is suited for programmers, we'd have to see some code.

Comment: @Ecnalyr thank you very much once more, clear and straight. 
I will try to be more aware about these things, as you understood I am a newbie at the game :) 

I've tried trough out the original source /woocommerce community/ but nobody seems to be active there unless I don't pay for the support.

Comment: Also, your update has some additional questions in it.  Remove those questions and create new question(s) for them.

Comment: @Ecnalyr So I have to delete my "answer/question" and create a brand new question for it, I got it correctly?

Comment: Well, you posted what should have been an update to this question as an answer.  (I updated this question to have the details from that unintentional 'answer').  Try to keep 'questions' as focused on one very specific problem as possible.  So don't delete this question / answer.  Leave it here, but create a new question with updated details to get the answer to the new question you now have.  The information contained within this question/answer is useful to you and likely useful to someone else in the future, so it needs to stay here.

Comment: A new question ( maybe with link to it in here ) wouldn't hurt, since this next issue seems to be a bit more complicated. In default setup, "add to cart" button is hooked after the before/after title hooks, which means the order change there might have something to do with CSS or perhaps there's more php code hiding somewhere that alters the template. A link to a demo site would be best.

Comment: New question ll come soon :) thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few more details relating to your parituclar setup are needed to give a proper answer. However, I'm going to assume you have everything at default. This is what you would need to add to the end of `functions.php` in your active theme folder:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

For reference, check https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product.php and https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php

If this does not work, check:

- that you use the latest version of woocommerce. Actually a few versions back should work the same, but not too far back.
- that your woocommerce templates are not overwritten. Check your theme folder for a file called `content-product.php` or in a subfolder `woocommerce/content-product.php`. If that has been altered, you need to adjust accordingly, perhaps by making changes right there.
- that your theme does not already mess around with product display hooks. If it does, find out what's different.

Please note that this changes behavior for all woocommerce loops, such as any shortcodes you might be using and the "related products" section in single product view, if that is enabled. To affect only categories, the changes should be wrapped in a condition check ( `is_product_category()` ).

Comment: That works like a charm. Great. Thank you.
I add another piece to the puzzle maybe you've got an idea

Answer (score 0):

If you put code into a plugin, you must wait for WooCommerce loading:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', function()
{
    // move product's title before product thumbnail instead of next to that
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
    add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this CSS for the product title and it worked fine for me. I used media query of course.

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
```